# dynamic form adding or removing not working after mapping values in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I made a dynamic form ,but When I save the values ​​that I got with API in ‍`haveFaq` and map them ,`removeFields` and `addFields` does not work
I save the values ​​that I receive from the API in `haveFaq` like this:

```
  [
    { question: "question1", answer: "answer1" },
    { question: "question2", answer: "answer2" },
    { question: "question3", answer: "answer3" },
  ];
```

```
  const [haveFaq, setHaveFaq] = useState([]);
  const [tempData, setTempData] = useState([
    {
      question: "",
      answer: "",
    },
  ]);

  const handleFormChange2 = (event, index) => {
    let data = [...tempData];
    data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setTempData(data);
  };

  const addFields = () => {
    let object = {
      question: "",
      answer: "",
    };

    setTempData([...tempData, object]);
  };

  const removeFields = (index) => {
    let data = [...tempData];

    data.splice(index, 1);
    setTempData(data);
  };
```

**Attention**
But if we map `tempData` instead of `haveFaq` The form works correctly,Because its initial values ​​are empty

```
         <>
              {haveFaq.map((form, index) => {
                return (
                  <div key={index + 1}>
                    <div className="form-row">
                      <div className="col-md-11 mb-3">
                        <label className="font-weight-bold" for="">
                          question
                        </label>
                        <input
                          className="form-control"
                          name="question"
                          placeholder="question"
                          onChange={(event) => handleFormChange2(event, index)}
                          value={form.question}
                          />
            
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-md-1 mt-4 iconSelf">
                        <p
                          className="btnRemove"
                          type="button"
                          onClick={() => removeFields(index)}
                        >
                          ❌
                        </p>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="form-row">
                      <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label className="font-weight-bold" for="">
                          answer
                        </label>
                        <textarea
                          rows={5}
                          className="lineHeightAnswer form-control"
                          name="answer"
                          placeholder="answer"
                          onChange={(event) => handleFormChange2(event, index)}
                          value={form.answer}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                  </div>
                );
              })}


              <div>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-info"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={addFields}
                  >
                    Add New
                  </button>
                </div>

            </>
```

Comment: You never use map on `tempData`. You map over `haveFaq`, but you functions change `tempData`

Comment: @Konrad because data is in `haveFaq` and the user must see its values and delete any one , or define a new input.

Comment: Copy `haveFaq` to `tempData` and map over `tempData`